# Disabling submit button based on checked state of radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coffeescript, disabled-input

So I've done some research on the proper way to do this, but I keep getting this error that I can't seem to get around.

I have a simple form being rendered a certain amount of times on my page, based on the models in the database (for instance I could have 2 forms on the page or 8).

What I'm currently trying is

```
$(document).ready ->
  elements = $('input:submit')
    elements.each (el) ->
      elements[el].disabled = true
      $(window).click ->
        if $(elements[el]).siblings('input:checked').length > 0
          elements[el].disabled = false
```

This code properly enables the button when a radio button is clicked.  But the radio button doesn't activate/respond to the click. When I try to submit the form, it tells me I haven't selected any input.

I've also tried

```
$(document).ready ->
  elements = $('input:submit')
    elements.each (el) ->
      elements[el].disabled = true
      $(window).click ->
        if $(elements[el]).siblings('input:checked').length > 0
          $(elements[el].removeAttr('disabled')
```

This code, on the other hand, allows me to check the radio button, but doesn't enable the submit button.

I figured maybe jQuery is recognizing my original code as a request to disable all elements within the `if $(elements[el]).siblings('input:checked').length > 0` query, so I tried making two separate blocks - one for initially disabling the submit buttons, and one to handle the clicks. But no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you post some proper code other than some representation.

Comment: Would you like to see the form?

Comment: Would be helpful if you shared html along with your form submission script.